# Fetch data but INSERT results only once a day

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function which fetches data from my database, it counts a number of instances existing for the same user and gives me a total figure. But I want to store this value in another table, which it does just fine the problem is that every time a user refreshes a page the same data is inserted and I want it to be inserted only once.

my function:

```
 public function getYesterday($user){

        $user = "SELECT user_id FROM tbl_user WHERE ott_email='$user'";
        $query = mysqli_query($this->con(), $user);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if($count == 1){

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $id = $row['user_id'];;
            }

                $yesterday = "SELECT COUNT(tbl_template_log.user_id) FROM tbl_template_log ";
                $yesterday .= "WHERE tbl_template_log.user_id='$id'";
                $yesterday .= " AND DATE(send_date) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
                $query_yesterday = mysqli_query($this->con(), $yesterday);
                $result = mysqli_fetch_row($query_yesterday);

                $insert = "INSERT INTO tbl_statistics (user_id, sta_count, sta_date)VALUES ('$id', '$result[0]', NOW())";
                mysqli_query($this->con(), $insert);

                echo $result[0];
        }
    }
```

Looking at my function logic and structure could someone suggest a correct solution to make sure the insert query is done only once per day.....?

I am using PHP, and MySQL

Comment: One method is to setup a column as UNIQUE.

Comment: What do you mean..? Sorry don't understand

Comment: Sorry, I misread it. I thought you meant that you were looking to enter unique data and avoiding a duplicate entry.

Comment: However after reading it again, setting up a column's type being UNIQUE will avoid just that. *"every time a user refreshes a page the same data is inserted and I want it to be inserted only once"* - which answers 50% of your question.

Comment: Before you insert check if an entry already exists for that user that day.